# Changing layout of STPPaymentCardTextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, stripe-payments

I add the TextField to my view using the steps shown in Stripe's docs.
But when I load the simulator, or run the app on my phone, the textfield is off bounds and the CVC textfield does not show on mobile. 
Is there a way to change the layout of the textfield to have the children (card no. , Exp date and CVC no.) all set up by columns rather than rows?

```
import UIKit
import Stripe

class ViewController: UIViewController, STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
    let paymentTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        paymentTextField.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 30, 44)
        paymentTextField.delegate = self


        view.addSubview(paymentTextField)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
        // Toggle navigation, for example
//        saveButton.enabled = textField.valid
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're experiencing probably has to do with using auto layout. If you're using auto layout (which is used by defect in new projects) when the `viewDidLoad` method is invoked the view sizes in the layout have not been calculated yet, in order to use the proper sizes calculated after applying the auto layout constraints you would have to use the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` callback (but you can't add the Stripe field there).

My proposed solution, if you want to keep using  `STPPaymentCardTextField`, is to use a container view of fixed size and then add the `STPPaymentCardTextField` to it with the fixed width.

On the other hand, answering your question, there is no way to change the STPPaymentCardTextField to be by columns instead of rows, but you can make your own implementation of it and request the token using the Stripe API Client (from: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom):

> **STPAPIClient + STPCardParams**: If you're collecting your users' card
>   details by using `STPPaymentCardTextField` or building your own credit
>   card form, you can use the STPAPIClient class to handle tokenizing
>   those details. First, assemble an `STPCardParams` object with the
>   information you've collected. Then, use `STPAPIClient` to convert that
>   into an `STPToken` which you can then pass to your server. (Note: the
>   examples in this guide assume you've written a function called
>   `submitTokenToBackend:completion:` which uses a networking library to
>   POST your `STPToken` to your server).